# polymorphism without classes in C#

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I am new to object-oriented programming. The problem is that when we define a method in a class, we can use that method in this way:

```
myobj.mymethod(params);
```

But I don't want my method be a member of the class, but still be a polymorphic function. I mean, I want it to be a "free" function that do different things based on its parameters. For example:

```
mymethod(myobjoftype1, intvar); // works with ints
mymethod(myobjoftype2, stringvar); // different function that works with strings
```

Is this possible in C#?

Comment: Sounds more like you want a *generic* method e.g. `mymethod<T>`, rather than a polymorphic one.

Comment: Use generic methods or extension methods

Comment: methods always have to be members of classes or structs. there's no concept of a "free" function in C#.

Comment: You can declare the method `static` if you don't want to create an instance of the class.

Comment: In C# Polymorphism can't be achieved without Classes, you need to look at Generics.

Comment: Do you want different functions chosen on the parameter types or one function which works uniformly with all parameter types? The first is done with overloading, the second with generics.

Comment: As you can see in the comments, you need to be clearer about either "not a member of a class" or "do different things based on its parameters". They are not related. The second question needs much more detail to be answerable.

Comment: You can achieve this with static functions. But please, do not go giving two functions - that do completely different things - the same name. That's not polymorphism, that's just creating difficult to read code.

Answer (score 2):

To make an 'independent method' is not possible in C# since there everything is a class or member of a class.

To your problem I would recommend using a [static](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx) class that only have static methods.

Usage:

```
ClassName.MethodName();
```

All the methods with different parameters should be implemented inside this certain class (method overloading).

But if it doesn't suit you, you should have a look at [generic methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx) (but in this case you also need to create at least 1 class).

Answer (score 0):

All methods or functions can be called from some owner (classes or structs)

```
namespace CustomNamespace
{
    // public static SomeFreeMethod(some params) { } <- This can't be in C#

    // For your case you can use code samples below
    public static class SomeStaticClass {

        public static void SomeMethod() { }

        public static void SomeMethod(object p1, object p2);

        public static void SomeMethod(object p1, object p2, object p3);

        public static T SomeMethod<T>(T o1, T o2, T o3) { return default(T); }
    }

    public class SomeInstanceClass {

        public SomeInstanceClass() {
          // call methods from static class in instance of object
          SomeStaticClass.SomeMethod();
          SomeStaticClass.SomeMethod(3, 6);
          SomeStaticClass.SomeMethod('c', "dasda", 3);
          float someResult = SomeStaticClass.SomeMethod<float>(3.45f, 312.233f, 3.14f);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be Type Dynamic can be useful for you.

The type is a static type, but an object of type dynamic bypasses static type checking.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this without using specific classes

I assume that you actually don't want to create classes just for the sake of method overloading.

```
public void Main() // Your main method
{
  mymethod("fff", 2); // Will call first mymethod
  mymethod(2.13, "ff"); // Will call second mymethod
}

void mymethod(string str, int intvar)
{
  Console.WriteLine("m1"); 
}

void mymethod(double flt, string stringvar)
{
  Console.WriteLine("m2"); 
}
```

[DEMO](http://volatileread.com/utilitylibrary/snippetcompiler?id=20688)

Comment: those have to be in a class.

Comment: Yes just the main program class, it's just if he wants to avoid writing classes just for his simple cause

Comment: @DanielA.White - The "not in a class" requirement looks like a red herring. Not achievable anyway, this is about the 2nd question.